# Elasticsearch load is not distributed evenly

Tags: elasticsearch

I am facing strange issue with Elasticsearch. I have 8 nodes with same configurations (16GB RAM and 8 core CPU).

One node "es53node6" has always high load as shown in the screenshot below. Also 5-6 nodes were getting stopped yesterday automatically after every 3-4 hours.

What could be the reason?

[image]

ES version : 5.3

Answer (score 0):

there can be a fair share of reasons. Maybe all data is stored on that node (which should not happen by default), maybe you are sending all the requests to this single node.

Also, there is no automatic stopping of Elasticsearch built-in. You can configure Elasticsearch that it stops the JVM process when an out-of-memory exception occurs, but this is not enabled by default as it relies on a more recent JVM.

You can use the [hot threads API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.4/cluster-nodes-hot-threads.html) to check where the CPU time is spent in Elasticsearch.